# Выборка из БД картинок PNG

Tags: php, zend-framework-3

Задать условие, что бы из БД получить все картинки с расширением **.png*.

Метод:

```
public function getFotoByParentIdWithPng ()
{
    $asutpService = $this->getAsutpRepository();
    $foto = ['parentId' => '2',
        'image' => 'sh1.png'];
    return $asutpService->findBy($foto);
}
```

он возвращаетиз БД все названия картинок которые соответствуют двум критериям.

Как правильно написать второй критерий в массиве, чтобы выдавало все файлы с расширением *.png*, а не как сейчас один файл *sh1.png*?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
'image' => 'LIKE "%.png"'
```

Comment: К сожалению, Zend такую конструкцию не понимает. Я уже пробовал.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не писать пользовательский запрос, использовал стандартный Доктриновский метод findBy. Получилось так

```
public function getFotoByParentIdWithPng ($menuId)
```

{
    $asutpService = $this->getAsutpRepository();

```
return $asutpService->findByParentId($menuId);
```

}

И уже во вьюхе или в помощнике видов (смотря где вы будете использовать данный запрос) перебираете в цикле объект с условием

```
foreach ($this->thumb as $item)
        {
            if (preg_match('/[a-z][0-9]+\.[png]+/i', $item['image'] ))
            {
                return $item;
            }
        }
```